# What is the best way to block incoming traffic from certain websites regardless of which port on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, networking, windows-firewall

When I open my web browser and navigate to [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com) , it will download all the text + graphics into my local machine for the web browser to interpret / view.

How could I tell windows to block all incoming traffic from [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com)?

So far, I have attempted to do the following with no success:

open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts as administrator which looks like:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost
```

Change it to look like:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost     https://www.cnn.com     http://www.cnn.com
#   ::1             localhost
```

I restarted my Windows 10 computer.  But when I tried to navigate to [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com) in my web browser, it was still able to successfully download all the data.

I tried to do:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

as suggested by [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot), however all the CNN packets were still being downloaded.

Has anybody been able to figure out a way to prevent packets from being downloaded from a specific IP address / URL ?

Do you think I need to use a firewall like [TinyWall](https://tinywall.pados.hu/) ?

Comment: You have efficiently written comments that contains the word `https://www.cnn.com     http://www.cnn.com` you would want to add a new line that contained only `127.0.0.1       cnn.com`.  However, the hosts file, is extremely inefficient way of blocking websites.

Comment: Note that this will not block traffic coming from CNN, but instead prevent you from requesting anything from that domain. not sure if that is a meaningful distinction to you or not. to actually block traffic you will need to use a firewall rather than the host file.

Answer (score 2):

#### All the CNN packets were still being downloaded.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost     https://www.cnn.com     http://www.cnn.com
```

The above is incorrect. You need to do something like the following:

```
127.0.0.1       cnn.com     
127.0.0.1       www.cnn.com
```

Note the file itself contains the instructions:

> Each entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
> be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
> The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
> space.

However, as pointed in a comment by Ramhound, changing the hosts file is not an efficient way of blocking websites